# How can I replace a block of code in a php file using preg_replace and regex expression?

Tags: php, regex, expression

I have a php config file that contains a few arrays use to store settings.

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
    "item1" => "value1",
    "item2" => "value2",
    "item3" => "value3",
    "item4" => "value4",
);
$array2 = array(
    "item1",
    "item2",
    "item3",
    "item4",
);
$array3 = array(
    "item1" => "value1",
    "item2" => "value2",
    "item3" => "value3",
    "item4" => "value4",
);
?>
```

I am not very good with regex expression (yet).I am having diffulties understanding how it works. I am trying to build a regex expression that would allow me to replace all lines in array2. Using `preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str)`.

```
$str=file_get_contents('config.php');
$pattern = "/[$array2 = array(](.*)[);]/";
$replacement = '    "itemA",
    "itemB",
    "itemC",
    "itemD",';
$str=preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
file_put_contents('config.php', $str);
```

The expected result would be :

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
    "item1" => "value1",
    "item2" => "value2",
    "item3" => "value3",
    "item4" => "value4",
);
$array2 = array(
    "itemA",
    "itemB",
    "itemC",
    "itemD",
);
$array3 = array(
    "item1" => "value1",
    "item2" => "value2",
    "item3" => "value3",
    "item4" => "value4",
);
?>
```

Comment: Use the tokenizer : https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, maybe some expression similar to

```
(\h{2,}"[^"\r\n]+")$
```

might work here to some level:

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iDBnMr/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/(\h{2,}"[^"\r\n]+")$/m';
$str = '$array1 = array(
    "item1\' => "value1",
    "item2\' => "value2",
    "item3\' => "value3",
    "item4\' => "value4",
);
$array2 = array(
    "item1"
    "item2"
    "item3"
    "item4"
);
$array3 = array(
    "item1\' => "value1",
    "item2\' => "value2",
    "item3\' => "value3",
    "item4\' => "value4",
);';
$subst = '$1,';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### Output

```
$array1 = array(
    "item1' => "value1",
    "item2' => "value2",
    "item3' => "value3",
    "item4' => "value4",
);
$array2 = array(
    "item1",
    "item2",
    "item3",
    "item4",
);
$array3 = array(
    "item1' => "value1",
    "item2' => "value2",
    "item3' => "value3",
    "item4' => "value4",
);
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iDBnMr/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/iDBnMr/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### Method 2

I guess, an expression similar to,

```
(?s)(?<=\$array2 = array\()[^)]*
```

might be OK to look into.

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/5IY3XR/1/)

```
$re = '/(?s)(?<=\$array2 = array\()[^)]*/';
$str = '$array1 = array(
    "item1" => "value1",
    "item2" => "value2",
    "item3" => "value3",
    "item4" => "value4",
);
$array2 = array(
    "item1",
    "item2",
    "item3",
    "item4",
);
$array3 = array(
    "item1" => "value1",
    "item2" => "value2",
    "item3" => "value3",
    "item4" => "value4",
);';
$subst = '\\n\\t"itemA",\\n\\t"itemB",\\n\\t"itemC",\\n\\t"itemD"\\n';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### Output 2

```
$array1 = array(
    "item1" => "value1",
    "item2" => "value2",
    "item3" => "value3",
    "item4" => "value4",
);
$array2 = array(\n\t"itemA",\n\t"itemB",\n\t"itemC",\n\t"itemD"\n);
$array3 = array(
    "item1" => "value1",
    "item2" => "value2",
    "item3" => "value3",
    "item4" => "value4",
);
```

Comment: let me correct the example, looks like I mixed some symbols there.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, I will definitely bookmark both links.

Comment: I might have a follow up question though. When replacing text with preg_replace, can I use an array to replace the occurence and add or remove lines?

Comment: so using the \n\r did not create newline as expected. here is what worked for me.
    $replacement = array('','    "itemA",','    "itemB",','    "itemC",','    "itemD",','');
    $str=file_get_contents('config.php');
    $str=preg_replace($pattern,implode(PHP_EOL, $replacement),$str);
    file_put_contents('config.php', $str);

Answer (score 0):

Firstly thanks @Emma for all the help. Here is the final code that worked for me simplified with the same example.

**config.php**

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
    "item1" => "value1",
    "item2" => "value2",
    "item3" => "value3",
    "item4" => "value4",
);
$array2 = array(
    "item1",
    "item2",
    "item3",
    "item4",
);
$array3 = array(
    "item1" => "value1",
    "item2" => "value2",
    "item3" => "value3",
    "item4" => "value4",
);
?>
```

PHP Code to manipulate the file :

```
<?php
function format_array($newarray){
    return('    "'.$newarray.'",');
}
$pattern = '/(?s)(?<=\$array2 = array\()[^)]*/';
$myarray = array(
    "itemA",
    "itemB",
    "itemC",
    "itemD",
);
$myarray = array_map("format_array",$myarray);
array_unshift($myarray, '');
array_pop($myarray);
array_push($myarray,'');
$str=file_get_contents('config.php');
$str=preg_replace($pattern,implode(PHP_EOL, $myarray),$str);
file_put_contents('config.php', $str);
?>
```

**Output**

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
    "item1" => "value1",
    "item2" => "value2",
    "item3" => "value3",
    "item4" => "value4",
);
$array2 = array(
    "itemA",
    "itemB",
    "itemC",
    "itemD",
);
$array3 = array(
    "item1" => "value1",
    "item2" => "value2",
    "item3" => "value3",
    "item4" => "value4",
);
?>
```

In order to get the expected result including the indents, I had to store the new array and create a leading empty element along with another one at the end. This makes sure that newlines are created in the file so we keep the same formatting.